# New equivalent of hdf5load

Tags: r, pointers, hdf5, hdf

Since the standard R package to manage HDF5 format has changed to `rhdf5`, some features are no longer available. One of those is `hdf5load`:

```
h5pointer = hdf5load(file=h5file,load=FALSE,verbosity=0,tidy=TRUE)
variable  = h5pointer$element
```

where `h5file` is the `HDF5` file to read in. One could solve the problem this way:

```
variable = h5read (h5file, "element")
```

The problem is that I have a huge number of those lines so this would mean to change a lot of code lines.

Is there a way to have an object like `h5pointer` from which I can later dereference the elements of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `rhdf 2.15.5` the utility is back. To update `rhdf` you need to have `R  >= 3.0.0`. Thanks to Bernd Fisher for adding it. Here's the 
[original discussion](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/79861/#82742).

Comment: there is still a problem, the old function had some arguments that the new function doesn't have ; load=FALSE,verbosity=0,tidy=TRUE

Comment: The $-operator is back, however the usage is now
`h5file = H5Fopen("file.h5")`
and then `h5file$A` so the only part that needs to be changed is the file loading (the old `hdf5load`)